# Hide Delphi FMX ListView separator lines and scrollbars

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm developing an iOS and Android App with Firemonkey and try to modify or hide the ListView separator lines between the items. How can I hide or modify them?

In addition, I want to hide also the vertical scrollbar. Is this possible on this component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.
Right click on ListView and select "Edit Custom Style..."
In Style Designer select "ListView1Style1" and set the Color of the "frame" item to be the same as Color of "background" item.

2.

```
var
  C: TControl;
begin
  for C in ListView1.Controls do
    if C is TScrollBar then
      C.Width := 0;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @dustypup! This is exactly what I was looking for!