# Remove separator lines for TListView on Delphi FMX

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, pascal, tlistview

Is it possible to remove the separator lines in the TListView? I have tried playing with the properties on TListView but still unable to remove the lines on it... Can anyone helped on this?

[image]

Comment: Please, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547624/hide-delphi-fmx-listview-separator-lines-and-scrollbars

Comment: i tried that method but the separator is still there...

Comment: Using `Delphi 10.4 CE` and following the instructions in the linked Q/A, I succeeded. So, first indicate with the tags, which version of Delphi you are using.  Then, by editing your question, describe the steps you took when you tried. Please, be precise in your description.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "DynamicAppearance" mode? but you will have to write the code manually, add an image and a text field in the "Structure" section, and manage everything in the "onUpdateObjects" event. Like this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var Voce : TListViewItem;
begin
      Voce := ListView1.Items.Add;
      Voce.Data['Text3'] := 'pippo 1';

      Voce := ListView1.Items.Add;
      Voce.Data['Text3'] := 'pippo 2';          
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
                                    const AItem: TListViewItem);
  var ImageItem : TListItemImage;
      TextItem1 : TListItemText;
begin
      ImageItem := AItem.Objects.DrawableByName('Image2') as TListItemImage;
      TextItem1 := AItem.Objects.DrawableByName('Text3') as TListItemText;

      If Assigned(ImageItem) Then
         Begin
         ImageItem.Bitmap := ImageList1.Bitmap(TSizeF.Create(16,16),0);
         //ImageItem.PlaceOffset.X := 0;
         //ImageItem.PlaceOffset.Y := 0;
         End;

      If Assigned(TextItem1) Then
         Textitem1.TextColor := claRed;
end;
```

In "ImageList1" there is a simple white image.

Comment: is it ok for you to share your prototype? I tried the code on my project but the border lines are still there...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's possible to act on "Custom Style" to obtain the effect you want, but I am not capable of it, for other reasons I have used this procedure which, probably, will serve your purpose. I have done some tests and it works quite well.

Put a ListView on the form.

In the section "Object Inspector":
ItemApperance\ItemEditAppearance\DynamicAppearance
ItemSpaces Left=0, Right=-10

In the section "Structure":
right click on "ListView1" and then "Toggle DesignMode"
expand "ListView1" and select "Item", in the properties click on "Addnew...\TImageObjectAppearance"

the image will contain a white bitmap (or other color) that will cover the signs between one item and another, on the form you see the structure of the item, you can manually modify the image as you wish, or write in the "onUpdateObjects" event some code, here is an example:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
                                    const AItem: TListViewItem);
  var ImageItem : TListItemImage;
      TextItem1 : TListItemText;
begin
      ImageItem := AItem.Objects.DrawableByName('Image2') as TListItemImage;
      TextItem1 := AItem.Objects.DrawableByName('Text1') as TListItemText;

      //ImageItem.Bitmap := Image1.Bitmap;
      ImageItem.Bitmap := ImageList1.Bitmap(TSizeF.Create(16,16),0);
      //ImageItem.Visible := True;
      //ImageItem.ScalingMode := TImageScalingMode.Stretch;

      ImageItem.PlaceOffset.Y := -1;
      ImageItem.PlaceOffset.X := 0;
      ImageItem.Height := 2;
      ImageItem.Width := Width;
end;
```

To add items to the list, you need to use this code:

```
var Voce : TListViewItem;
begin
      Voce := ListView1.Items.Add;
      Voce.Data['Text1'] := 'pippo 1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ListviewStyle.Frame.color` property and set it equal to `ListviewStyle.background.color` property.

Many ways to accomplish this :

- Change default style
- Modify the custom style
- Coding (but that's another challenge)